Detecting iOS user biometric database changed after 18.0?
Since evaluatedPolicyDomainState is marked as "Deprecated" after 18.0
Is there any other ways to detecting the authorized database change (Updating FaceID / Touch ID)?
Currently I am saving the "context.evaluatedPolicyDomainState" to KeyChain and verify it before the next biometric evaluate policy.
Just wondering any other method can do the same thing after evaluatedPolicyDomainState deprecated.

There doesn't seem to be a replacement.  You can continue to use the deprecated approach until it is removed (likely to be some time before that happens) or you could store a value in the Keychain with the biometryCurrentSet access flag and let Keychain take care of things for you
